# Determining phase from intermolecular interactions and kinetic energy

Tags: phase

If the energy of intermolecular attractions are much less than the average kinetic energy of the molecules, what is the physical state of the substance?

Comment: Interesting that plasma is an option. Plasmas are actually strongly self-interacting, in a way that is *hellish* to describe mathematically; the interactions are long-ranged (electric force goes as $1/r^2$), there are strong higher order effects (magnetism) and there are both attractive and repulsive interactions between particles. No wonder plasma physics is a tough nut to crack. It's been keeping nuclear fusion power generation out of reach for decades!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely gas.

In fact, the definition of an ideal gas is a gas in which its molecules have no intermolecular interactions (except elastic collisions).

As the strength of intermolecular attraction increases, the molecules will be brought closer together. Molecules in liquids are much more densely packed than molecules in gases.